# Passing data from SQLite db into specific components

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, sqlite, data-binding

I have an sqlite db in an application and am stuck on how to pass the data that is retrieved from the db into multiple textboxes.  I can get the first selection passed into the components just fine, but my problem comes in when I try to pass a second data selection into a different textbox while keeping the data from the previous selection the same in the first textbox.

Basically, the user selects a recipe and that recipe is passed into textbox 1.  Then another recipe is selected and that recipe is passed into textbox 2.  *The recipes are selected from a different view, if that adds anything to the problem.  After being selected, the view is returned to where the textboxes are.

I'm not looking for someone to code this for me, but rather on how I would do it.  I should be able to do that. =)

Thank you so much for any and all advice.

**My Text Components**

```
<s:Group id="group1" x="412" y="156" width="200" height="206" contentBackgroundAlpha="1.0" >
        <s:TextInput id="tText1" x="22" y="30" width="157" height="25" fontSize="12"
                     text="{data.kTitle}"/>
        <s:TextArea id="iText1" x="11" y="63" width="178" height="133" editable="false" fontSize="12"
                    text="{data.kIngredients}"/>
        <s:Label id="timer1" x="174" y="8" click="timer1_clickHandler(event)" fontSize="13"
                 text="00"/>
        <s:Label x="169" y="7" fontSize="13" text=":"/>
    </s:Group>
    <s:Group id="group2" x="754" y="37" width="200" height="206" visible="false">
        <s:TextInput id="tText2" x="22" y="28" width="157" height="26" fontSize="12"  text="{data.kIngredients}"/>
        <s:TextArea id="iText2" x="10" y="63" width="178" height="133" editable="false" fontSize="12" text="{data.kTitle}"/>
        <s:Label id="timer2" x="176" y="7" click="timer2_clickHandler(event)" fontSize="13" text="00"/>
        <s:Label x="173" y="7" fontSize="13" text=":"/>
    </s:Group>
```

**Upon clicking "make the recipe" button - pushes recipe data back to main view**

```
protected function viewRecipeButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void  // make recipe button pushed
            {
                if(recipeList.selectedItem != null)
                    navigator.pushView(views.Timer_view, recipeList.selectedItem);
            }
```

**How I'm getting the SQlite data**

```
protected function getAllRecipes():void   // get all the recipes from the DB
            {
                var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
                var conn:SQLConnection = new SQLConnection();
                stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
                conn.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("Recipes.db"));
                stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM kItems WHERE kTitle IS NOT NULL";
                stmt.execute();
                recipeList.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(stmt.getResult().data);
                conn.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want are item renderers, possibly in a List or DataGroup.  What you need to do is send your data over in an array, pass that array to a List and have the list display the information you need.  In your cause it would be something like this:

```
 <s:List dataProvider="{recipes}">
   <s:itemRenderer>
      <fx:Component>
         <fx:ItemRenderer>
            <s:TextInput text="{data.kTitle}"/>
            <s:TextArea text="{data.kIngredients}"/>
         </fx:ItemRenderer>
      </fx:Component>
   </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

Comment: @J_A_X, thanks for the reply.  My only question is, how would I be able to ensure that when I passed the new title and ingredients, that all the "textArea and TextInputs" wouldn't be overwritten with the newly passed data?  If I create an itemRenderer for each set of Title and Ingredients, I would still need to bind it using, "data.kTitle and data.kIngredients" correct?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question.  When you have new data, it will rebind and remove whatever you had placed in the text input unless you code it otherwise.

Comment: right, what I would like to have happen, is textInput1 and textArea1 keep their data.  Then when the user picks a new recipe, textInput2 and textArea2 are loaded with the new selected data and set 1 keep their original data in place.

Comment: Gotcha.  I know what you're trying to do now, but what about the UI?  Do you want actually a tabbed interface or a list of recipes where the user can select?

Comment: what I'm doing right now, is pushing a view that contains the list of recipes for them to select from, I'm not sure if a tabbed interface would be more effective tho.  I've never used one.

Comment: @J_A_X, after taking a look at the tabbed interface, I think i'd still stay with standard views.

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to do.  Think you could post some sort of imagery of what you want?